# Android Studio new project initialization issue

Tags: android, android-activity

When create empty android project with no activity by default, and then add empty activity through android studio GUI, debug is showing error
`Waiting for application to come online`
Manifest file seems to be fine, what step in app setup might have been missed? When creating project with empty activity by default, there is no error

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.lib_name"
            android:value="" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried to compare contents of two new created project, one with manually added `mainActivity` and another project with empty activity created by default, but it seems no diff

Comment: are you deleting the app and running again?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project and rebuild it , then try again